# Loop through specific keys in array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am accessing a json decoded array

```
$orders = json_decode($response, true);
```

And then within the an array called DATA, I am going through each order and finding the Total key.

```
// access the common array
$orders = $orders['data'];

// access the total of each order
$sale1 = $orders[0]['total'];
$sale2 = $orders[1]['total'];
$sale3 = $orders[2]['total'];
$sale4 = $orders[3]['total'];
$sale5 = $orders[4]['total'];
$sale6 = $orders[5]['total'];
$sale7 = $orders[6]['total'];
```

Then i'm adding them up to get the combined total of all orders.

```
// add up all orders to find total
echo $sale1 + $sale2 + $sale3 + $sale4 + $sale5 + $sale6
```

I cant figure out how to make this into a loop.

Here is my array:

```
array(3) {

   [0]=>
   array(53) {
    ["total"]=>
     int(100)
    }

   [1]=>
   array(53) {
    ["total"]=>
     int(100)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do -

```
$total = 0;
foreach($orders as $key => $order) {
    $total += $order['total']; // add up the total
}

echo $total;
```

Or if you have latest or greater than `5.5.0` `PHP` version then -

```
echo array_sum(array_column($orders, 'total'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to specify the index key in $orders.

```
$temp = json_decode($response, true);
$orders = $temp['data'];
$len = count($orders);

for($i=0; $i < $len; $i++)
{
    $total += $orders[$i]['total'];
}

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have following array

```
$arr = array('0'=>array("total"=>100),
      '1'=>array("total"=>100),
        '2'=>array("total"=>100),
        '3'=>array("total"=>100),
        '4'=>array("total"=>100),
        '5'=>array("total"=>100),
        '6'=>array("total"=>100));
```

And you want to add value using loop then use following statement

```
$total = 0;
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
    $total += $val['total'];
}

echo $total;//it will return 700 which is total value.
```